# Matrix linear combinations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Write the matrix $E=\begin{bmatrix}3&1\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}$ as a linear combination of the matrices $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}, B=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix},C=\begin{bmatrix}0&2\\0&-1\end{bmatrix} $$ I only knew how this would look like, $$\begin{bmatrix}3&1\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}=x\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}+y\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}+z\begin{bmatrix}0&2\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: That’s a good start. Now expand that sum to get a system of linear equations in the three unknowns and solve it. As Bob Kari suggests below, you can find $x$ by inspection.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

\begin{align}\begin{bmatrix}3&1\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}&=x\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}+y\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}+z\begin{bmatrix}0&2\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}\\&=
\begin{bmatrix}x&x\\x&0\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\y&y\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0&2z\\0&-z\end{bmatrix}\\&=
\begin{bmatrix}x&x+2z\\x+y&y-z\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

therefore

$$x=3$$
$$x+2z=1\implies z=-1$$
$$y-z=-1 \implies y=-2$$

hence

\begin{align}\begin{bmatrix}3&1\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}&=3\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}-2\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}-1\begin{bmatrix}0&2\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $x=3$ since all the other matrices have $0$ at the position $(1,1)$. Then notice that since your last matrix has a $0$ at the position $(2,1)$, $y$ has to equal to equal $-2$ to satisfy $1=3(1)+y$.

Then solve for $z$ to get $z=-1$ (found by considering the position $(1,2)$